# Delete all text up to a character

Tags: javascript, regex

I currently have a url path like so:

```
var str = "http://stackoverflow.com/i-like-upvotes/you-do-too";
```

I wish to delete/remove all the string up to the last `/` slash.

If I wanted to replace the last slash I'd get it like this:

```
console.log(str.replace(/\/(?=[^\/]*$)/, '#'));
```

But I would like to delete everything up to the last slash and I can't figure it out.
In the above example I'd get back

```
you-do-too
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Fixed, thank you! @Barmar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var str = "http://stackoverflow.com/i-like-upvotes/you-do-too";
console.log(str.replace(/^.*\//, ''));
```

- `^` matches the beginning of the string.
- `.*` matches anything.
- `\/` matches slash.

Since `.*` is greedy, this will match everything up to the last slash. We delete it by replacing with an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not beautiful, but you can do `str.split('/').pop()` to get the last part of the URL.
No un-humanly readable regex

Comment: Some people like stuff that's not beautiful as long as it works.  That's why my wife chose me!